# Rapportive details save to google contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, contacts

Is there any option to save updated contact details provided by Rapportive to google contacts ?
Any greasemonkey script or Firefox plugins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen that sort of Greasemonkey script of Firefox plugin, but conceivably it would be doable to rig up something to that effect. It all depends on Rapportive's Terms of Service, however.

Programmatically, Rapportive doesn't currently offer an outbound API - they currently only offer a way to programmatically send info *to* them regarding contacts. So you'd have to go about it another way. Scraping the info that's displayed *could* be an option - but I'd do due diligence first & be sure to read their policies. They might prohibit that sort of thing (they're owned by LinkedIn, whose TOS are known to be very restrictive).

You could also accomplish this sort of thing using [FullContact](http://www.fullcontact.com) (disclosure - my company). Our Address Book app (in beta) adds photos, social profile links, titles, etc. - the same sort of data returned by Rapportive - to Google Contacts and syncs in real-time.

We don't use Rapportive's data - the data is all public social profile data, returned by our social profile APIs - but the Address Book should help you do exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: UPDATE - (Again, this is talking about my company's app, so same disclaimers apply) - last year we also released a Chrome extension called [FullContact for Gmail](https://www.fullcontact.com/gmail/) that does exactly what you're looking for. Hover over an email address in Gmail, see that person's social info - and if you want, add it all to Google Contacts with one click. Just saw a notification about this question, and realized it warranted an update.